# Eclipse: Run as cucumber features

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I can't run cucumber features from eclipse. When I right click in a feature file the option run as > cucumber feature is available, but when I used it nothing happens, even no errors show up...

- I have cucumber plugin installed, even reinstalled
- From terminal the tests runs well (mvn clean tests)
- In intellij it works
- Eclipse version neon

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You should run it through testrunner file . Need to create testNG or junit test runner then trigger it

Comment: Test runners are generated by the cucumber-parallel plugin at runtime, I don't have them in my source code

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. For whatever reason it doesn't work from the project explorer but if you open up the feature and right click in the editor it should work from there.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an actual answer.

Comment: You need at least 50 reputation to comment. Also this did answer the question. Why should it be a comment instead?